# Run time for inserting a binary search tree is n^2?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, binary-search-tree

The book says the worst run time of inserting a binary search tree is n^2

I don't really get it.

I mean if you have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

which is the worst case, isn't the worst case run time is O(n)?

(if value < node.data, go to left, if > node.data go right)

Can anyone explain? I would really appreciate that!

---

I think I got the answer now! because you need to go back to find if the new number
is greater or smaller from the beginning.

But I have another question now, whats the worst case run time of building a AVL tree?

The book says build and sort a binary search tree is n(log n)

the worst depth of a AVL tree is log n

it never said what's the inserting time of a entire AVL tree.

anyone knows?

Comment: Where did you get that number from? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree that type of tree is worstcase O(n) when you always go right because your tree is actually a list. More than that would involve re-balancing the tree.

Comment: Inserting a single value is O(n). Generating the whole tree is 1 + 2 + 3... + n operations which is O(n^2)

Comment: I know that find a value in a worst case binary tree is O(n) because its a list so you have to go through all numbers. But the build time of a binary tree is n^2, you can check George's answer, he explained it pretty clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, anyone knows the second question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `O(n)` because on each insertion you need to go through the whole tree to find a suitable location to place the new node.

For instance, at first you place a 1 at the head of the node. Then, to place the 2, you need to look at the 1 at the head and decide to add the 2 to the right of the head. Then, when adding the 3, you need to look at that 1 again, decide to go right, then look at the 2 and put the 3 on the right node of the 2.

So basically, each worst case insertion is `O(k)` (where k is the number elements already in the tree). To build the tree you need to do n insertions, so the whole operation takes `1+2+3+4+5+6...+n` operations which is `O(n^2/2)` --> `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really clear. Do you mind I ask another question? What's the worst case run time for inserting a AVL tree. I see that insert + sort a bst is n(logn) and the worst depth of avl tree is log n, I'm kind of confused, so is inserting a avl tree nlogn or logn?

Comment: Both the worst and average case insertion to an AVL tree is O(log(n)). The is because to add a node you'll have to spend one operation at each row of the tree, and there are maximum log(n) total rows max since it is balanced. To build the whole tree, multiply this by n. So you get O(n(log(n)).

Comment: Actually, each insertion is `Ω(k)` where `k` is the number of already inserted elements. Turns out the total runtime is still `Ω(n²)` because `1 + 2 + ... + n =~ n²/2`

Comment: @NiklasB. You are correct. I've modified my answer accordingly; Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the depth of an AVL Tree:
Let N(h) denote the no. of nodes in an AVL Tree of height h.
    N(h) >= 1+N(h-1) + N(h-2), this comes from the definition of the AVL Tree.
    N(h) >= F(h)-1, where F(h) is the Fibonacci no.
    N(h) >= {(1+sqrt(5)/2}^h,
therefore h <= log (with base=(1+sqrt(5))/2) n.
so h <=  c logn. base=2;`
Now looking at the above input where we want to insert 1,2,3,...,n.
Now rotation will take place in constant time.
After every two element insertion, one rotation occurs. So no of rotations=n/2.
And every time we need to do logm comparisons where logm is the current height.
So total operations = c(log 1+ log 2+ log 3+ log 4+ .... +log n-1) + n/2
which is equal to c(log (n-1)!) + n/2
<= c(nlogn) + n/2 , which is nothing but O(nlogn).
 PS:logn implies base of 2.

Comment: But the book says the wors depth of AVL tree is logn?

Comment: @user2913922 That's correct for single insertions. `nlog(n)` is the time to build the entire tree, not a single insertion.